# @react-native-async-storage/async-storage doesn't work when generating ipa or apk with expo

Tags: expo, asyncstorage

Hi I'm having a problem with "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" hope someone can help me.

In Development environment it works perfectly, but when I generate an apk or ipa it doesn't work.

I'm using Expo version 41

Comment: Can you explain bit more what happens on apk?

Comment: Can you provide a log of your error?

Comment: @GabrielMenezesdaSilva 
Hello, in development environment it doesn't return any error, but when I generate the apk it just doesn't work localstorage

Comment: @KamalHossain Nothing happens when I press register it just doesn't do what I want, which is to save the data to storage

Comment: @eadafonso24 I am using `@react-native-community/async-storage` instead of `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` in an expo project. Working perfectly fine. You can try this.

Comment: I think it must has a native Log of the error. You can try to see the error in debug mode in Android Studio, in the Logcat to provide us more details about the error.